# AWS Lambda unzip and upload thousands of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 2 S3 buckets. Bucket A is where a zip file gets uploaded to and bucket B contains the extracted data from the latest zip that was uploaded to bucket A. I have a Lambda that triggers upon a object create event from bucket A, it then extracts the zip as a stream and uploads to bucket B. Here is the code:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const s3Client = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const sourceBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const zip = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: sourceBucket,
        Key: zip
    };

    const zip = s3Client.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream().pipe(unzipper.Parse({ forceStream: true }));
    const promises = [];

    for await (const file of zip) {
        const type = file.type;
        if (type === 'File') {
            const fileName = file.path;

            const params = {
                Bucket: process.env.DEST_BUCKET,
                Key: `${fileName}`,
                Body: file,
            };
            promises.push(s3Client.upload(params).promise());
        } else {
            file.autodrain();
        }
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
};
```

The problem is the zip is about 200MB with over 10,000 files and folders in it. The lambda, even set at 900 seconds, is timing out. Is there a more efficient way to write the above code to utilize something like parallel streams or rewriting of the for-loop?

Comment: Maybe you may use Golang.

Comment: If your code runs longer than the permitted 15 minutes, then either try increasing the assigned memory (which also increases the CPU allocation) or find another way to run the code (eg on an Amazon EC2 instance). Your use-case is not suitable for AWS Lambda. (Most AWS Lambda executions run for less than one second.)

Comment: You can try setting the memory size to max: 10240 as well